# Remote catalog is empty

Tags: m2e, spring-tool-suite, m2e-wtp

Getting a Remote catalog is empty message for an archetype catalog I have been using for years.  Searches only reference some old version of m2eclipse.  I am using the STS 3.6.2 Windows latest release which has m2e version 1.4.1.20140328-1905 and m2e-wtp version 1.0.1.20130911-1545.

I have:
1) Double checked connectivity and verified the catalog has not changed.
2) Downloaded the catalog to my local machine and attempted to load it as a local catalog, which yields the exact same result.
3) Searched the internet for a solution to the issue.

Please I need some help from the STS community or STS personnel.

Comment: Now sure what might cause this. Did you try a fresh STS installation to see if that works? And/or a fresh Eclipse installation with m2e installed, so see if the problem is related to m2e/Maven or the STS distribution?

Comment: I also often clean the local Maven repository (~/.m2/repository) if something goes wrong with Maven. I know, this is kind of a stupid trial/error idea, but sometimes the local repository is corrupted and deleting it helps.